# sending raw transaction unsuccessful

Tags: light-clients, signature, raw-transaction

I am developing a light wallet for a private network. I use ethereumjs-accounts for storing accounts locally and ethereum-tx for signing transactions. I have deployed custom token-contract. Here is my `txParams` object:

```
        nonce: nonce, //transaction count
        gasPrice: "0x0", //private network do not need gas
        gas: "0x0",
        from: account, //sender account
        to: contractParams.address,
        value: "0x0",
        data: this.contractInstance.sendFunds.getData(
            '0x07a204163f78bf9293c996f8c6d98a058a324b2d',
            '0xd9f0443219296744c91929fc0818b3e42d90b2eb',
            2,
            ''
        ) //calling functions to send tokens from 1 account to another
```

Than I sign the transaction and send it to the chain:

```
    let tx = new EthereumTx(txParams);

    tx.sign(privateKey);

    let serializedTx = '0x' + tx.serialize().toString('hex');

    this.web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(serializedTx, (err, hash) => {
        if(err) {
            console.info(err);
        }else{
            console.log('Transaction hash: ', hash);
        }
    });
```

After sending the transaction I receive tx hash but nothing more happens. I can get transaction by hash for 30-40 seconds after sending and then the transaction disappears, and if I try to get it after 40 seconds - I get `null`.

**Any ideas what can cause this problem and how to debug it?**

Transaction object `from web3.eth.getTransaction();`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are `nonce` and `contractParams.address` both hex-encoded with a leading `0x` prefix?

ps) it would be a good idea to pad all hex-encoded values with a leading `0` if the length is odd.. to ensure that the length is even. (ie: `0x1` should be entered as `0x01`, etc)

pps) `txParams.from` can be removed.. it has no meaning

Comment: Thanks for comment. Problem solved, but was at anotyher sing. Don't know why, but web3js couldn't get public key to fill `from` field. I have reinstalled lib and it works now.